# Can a Windows Driver detect and reveal which Windows Kit it was built with?

Tags: wdk

or can the compiler detect which WDK version it has included?

At my company real release builds are done with a golden build machine. But each developer does all their R&D with their own MS VS 2022 on their own laptop. I suspect their settings, downloads, add-ons etc aren't 100% correct. So I was going to make the driver itself debug print out which Windows Kit it was built with. (Everyone is there with their Windbg opened anyway.) So I can definitively say whether people are doing their builds correctly during development time.

(RtlGetVersion tells you which OS you're running on. But it doesn't give the driver any info about the driver itself.)